# How to pivot or transpose partial data frame with aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df` where the combination of 5 columns: `item, fav_topping, cheese, crust, order_yr_month` is unique. There are 1450 rows.

```
        item    fav_topping   cheese   crust    order_yr_month  #_of_orders
0       Pizza   Pineapple       PPJ     Thin        2020-12         0
1       Pizza   Pineapple       PPJ     Thick       2021-01         0
2       Pizza   Pineapple       PPJ     Thin        2021-02         0
3       Pizza   Pineapple       PPJ     Thick       2021-03         0
4       Pizza   Pineapple       PPJ     Pan         2021-04         9
...               ...              ...      ...     ...   ...       ...
1446    Sandwich    Pickles     CHD     Pan         2022-07         91
1447    Sandwich    Pickles     CHD     Thick       2022-08         91
1448    Sandwich    Pickles     CHD     Thin        2022-09         11
1449    Sandwich    Pickles     CHD     Cheese      2022-10         12
1450    Sandwich    Pickles     CHD     Cheese      2027-12         0
```

I want to convert this to `result_df` which needs to be exported to excel where the unique `order_yr_month` needs to be transposed and the `#_of_orders` must be aggregated. Notice the number of rows (65) now has the unique combination of only 4 columns `item, fav_topping, cheese, crust`

```
        item    fav_topping   cheese   crust    2020-12     2021-01     2021-02     2021-03     2021-04     2022-07     2022-08     2022-09     2022-10     
0       Pizza   Pineapple       PPJ     Thin        0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
1       Pizza   Pineapple       PPJ     Thick       0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2       Pizza   Pineapple       PPJ     Cheese      0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
3       Pizza   Pineapple       PPJ     Roast       0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
4       Pizza   Pineapple       PPJ     Pan         0           0           0           0           9           0           0           0           0
...               ...              ...      ...    
61      Sandwich    Pickles     CHD     Pan         0           0           0           0           0           91          0           0           0
62      Sandwich    Pickles     CHD     Thick       0           0           0           0           0           0           91          0           0
63      Sandwich    Pickles     CHD     Thin        0           0           0           0           0           0           0           11          0
64      Sandwich    Pickles     CHD     Cheese      0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           12
65      Sandwich    Pickles     CHD     Roast       0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
```

What is the pandas way of doing this?

**My attempts all failed:**

1. Using pivot_table on partial table?
2. Using transpose
3. Using multiindex
4. Extracting sub table `index, order_yr_month, #_of_orders` and then transposing them. - The problem here is that the year-month columns are unique in `result_df` however not all rows in `df` have all those columns.

UPDATE:

@jezrael pointed me to the right solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)
After reading [crosstab docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) -

This is what worked -

```
result_df = pd.crosstab(index=[df['item'],df['fav_topping'],df['cheese'],df['crust']], columns=df['order_yr_month'],  values=df['orders'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: Can you add your pivot code which failed to question?

Comment: @jezrael trying this right now - `pd.crosstab(index=['item','fav_topping','cheese','crust'], columns=['order_yr_month'],  values=['#_of_orders'], aggfunc='sum')`

Comment: hmmm, I think pivot_table solution. Maybe need `df.pivot_table(index=['item','fav_topping','cheese','crust'], columns='order_yr_month',  values='#_of_orders', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)`

Comment: If failed, can you explain more?

Comment: It worked like a charm man! Thank you so much for pointing to the right question. 

I'll update the question with the right solution.